# Maintaining Agent state while returning in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm fetching url's via proxies, where each agent's state is a vector containing the proxy host and port it fetches from.

I'm trying to return the content's of the page fetched while maintaining the agent's state as the vector containing the host and port.

This is what I have so far.

```
(defn fetch-url-with-proxy [url]
  (letfn [(fetch-fn [host-port url]
            (let [[host port] host-port]
              (fetch-url url host port)
              host-port))]
    (send-off (agent-from-pool proxy-pool) fetch-fn url)))
```

Unfortunately I currently return the agent, not the content of the fetch-url.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a promise to wait for the result:

```
(defn fetch-url-with-proxy [url]
  (letfn [(fetch-fn [host-port url result]
      (let [[host port] host-port]
        (deliver result (fetch-url url host port))
          host-port))]
  (let [result (promise)]
    (send-off (agent-from-pool proxy-pool) fetch-fn url result)
    @result)))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to return, it just hangs... I thought it did work earlier, but it doesn't appear to consistently work.

Comment: Is it possible that fetch-url is throwing an exception?

Comment: Actually, it seems to be opening ```*sldb clojure/1*<2>```, which is a behaviour I've not seen before, using swank in emacs if that helps.

Comment: Hanging means that the fetch-url thread hasn't finish or it has thrown an exception. Can you try to put a try/catch around the deliver function call and println the exception? If you still don't see the exception, you should do a thread-dump to see what is the fetch-url thread doing

Comment: Thanks, found the error, I was passing it into ```enlive```, but enlive's ```html-resource``` does not accept strings, you need to wrap it in a ```java.io.StringReader.```. Much appreciated!